# Share the same ajax result between three different sections/divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

My ajax call is returning 27 results, and I need to split these results in to three equal parts, so 9 results for each sections, which are displayed below.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content">

   <section>
   </section>

   <section>
   </section>

   <section>
   </section>

</div>
```

**JS** looks roughly like this. Currently, all of the 27 results are going inside of every sections. How do I define the method for each of my sections to take only 9 results inside of them?

```
var query = "http://ajaxcallfromservice&maxResults=27";
$.ajax({
    url: query,
    async: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (result) {
        ajax.parseJSONP(result);
    }
});

var ajax = {
    parseJSONP : function(result) {
        $.each(result.items, function(i, row) {
                $('section').append('<h2'+ row.stuffWhatINeed +'</h2>');                    
        });
    }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should add that there can also be different amount of results, but the point being that it should be divided equally between the divs somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to append to the *correct* section. Assuming you want the first 9 in the first section, etc...

```
var ajax = {
  parseJSONP : function(result) {

    var sections = $('section');
    var perSection = Math.ceil(result.items.length / sections.length);   // will be 9

    $.each(result.items, function(i, row) {
      var secNo = Math.floor(i / perSection);  // 0 for 0..8, 1 for 9..17, 2 for 18..26

      sections[secNo].append('<h2>'+ row.stuffWhatINeed +'</h2>');                    
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer, it cleared a lot of stuff.